# Cannot start emulator symbol not found _AVMediaTypeVideo

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am unable to start emulator. It is giving this error

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output
dyld:symbol not found _AVMediaTypeVideo
```

I have tried restarting Android Studio, rebooting the system. Can anyone help?

Happens after upgrading Android SDK Tools to 24.1.2 rev 24.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to SDK Tools from 24.3.1 to 24.3.3 fixed this issue for me.  You can update the SDK Tools via the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem on my MacBook Pro yesterday with the latest version of Android SDK tools (i.e., 24.3.1). I found that updating my MacOS X to OS X Yosemite resolved the issue. Now, my emulators are starting again.

I am going to assume they are using some symbols that are only available in Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I downloaded the SDK separately and changed the SDK location in Android Studio to use the downloaded one. Now the emulator starts up again.

Comment: It seems that this is caused by SDK Tools 24.3

Comment: Same problem here. Downloading SDK didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried downloading "android-sdk_r24.2-macosx.zip" for Mac and then change the SDK location in Android Studio to  the unzipped files?

Comment: Yes that didn't help. Updating Mac OS X from 10.8 to 10.10 helped.